# 16 Genders of the Kivunjo Language?

Tags: grammar, gender, bantu

Some of the Bantu languages have many grammatical genders. One of these, Kivunjo, is said to have 16. Would anyone let me know all of the 16 genders?

Steven Pinker’s *The Language Instinct* quotes Kivunjo as having 16 genders. These are not 16 sexual identities, they are 16 families of nouns classified according to how verbs agree with them.

Comment: I don't know about Kivunjo specifically, but in most bantu languages the noun classes don't all have neat interpretations the way european-style genders do. This, combined with the fact some are singular, some plural, and some singulars have the same plural etc all mean that calling them genders isn't typically done, and they're usually just referred to by number (or occasionally by the class prefix itself)

Comment: "Kivunjo is one of several dialects of Chagga language". Google African Journals online. You need to show some research effort of your own.

Comment: What do you mean by "know the genders"? The numbers? The prefixes on nouns? the agreement morphemes? putative semantic correlations? relation to Proto-Bantu? NB we call then "noun classes", we use "gender" to refer to the pairs, such as "1-2", "3-4" where 1, 2, 3, 4... are the conventional classes.

Comment: You'll find information about genders in the closely related Chagga-Mochi [in this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/372538600_Noun_Structure_and_Classification_in_Chagga-Mochi).

Comment: Thank you very much, Omar and Lorraine,  for having me read a very instructive paper, which seems to show that genders in Kivunjo are only the classes of nouns in the language.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to compare these noun classes to declensions rather than genders?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni — Declensions presuppose the existence of the system of cases in the language in question which is not found in the Bantu languages. The real declension defines how the noun itself behaves, but the Bantu class defines how other words behave, the ones that are in "agreement" or "concord" with this noun.

Comment: @samhana — The preferred term is rather ‘class’ than ‘gender’ since among those various criteria that define which class a Bantu noun belongs to there's none that deals with the biological sex, the gender proper, even the distinction of the personal pronouns ‘he’ vs. ‘she’ is absent.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no, because there's agreement. Adjectives and verbs agree on noun class (just as they would gender). Declensions are _not_ agreed with. E.g. looking at Latin, let's take the adjective bonus. This always follows the first & second declension, even when describing a third declension noun. It is "rex bonus" "a good king" and not *"rex bons(?)", because gender/noun class causes agreement, whilst declension does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know Kivunjo specifically, in most Bantu languages, the noun genders/noun classes tend not to have clear interpretations.

Even in languages with fewer than 16 genders, the gender doesn't always have a meaning. German has a neuter gender, so shouldn't all inanimate objects be neuter? What's male or female about a table? Or, for that matter, what's neuter about a young girl?

When you have over a dozen noun classes, this problem only gets worse. In Bantu studies, they're generally just referred to with numbers, instead of trying to name them. You can find general tendencies—people are in class 1, artifacts are in class 7, animals are in class 9—but just like in German, they're no more than tendencies. There's no particular reason why *yai* "egg" is class 5 (in Swahili at least) besides "that's just how it's always been".

(I can tell you what all of these general tendencies are in Swahili or Lingála, if what you're interested in is "how do you come up with 16 categories to put nouns into", but if you want to know about Kivunjo specifically, you'll need to wait for a speaker of that language.)

Comment: I've got one nitpick and that is that grammatical gender is not a feature of some object. It's a feature of the noun that denotes it! That is, eggs aren't class 5. It's the Swahili noun, "yai", which is class 5.

Comment: @OmarandLorraine Fair point; I was using "egg" in quotes to stand in for _yai_ for simplicity but of course English words don't have noun classes either.

Comment: It might help to note that, where singular and plural are distinguished, they are traditionally counted as separate classes – if I understand right.